# Is there a hotkey to open the grouping menu in Terminator?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, hotkeys, terminator

I use Terminator for everything with just the keyboard, the only thing that requires the mouse is:

- Grouping menu -> New group
- Grouping menu -> Split to this group (only once per restart of OS)

Does anybody know if there's a hotkey for selecting group menu, or any of the underlying functions mentioned in the mentioned bullet points?

The docs ([Terminator grouping menu](https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/grouping.html#grouping-menu)) seem to not mention anything, but any advice is greatly appreciated.

Note: `SHIFT + F10` only does right mouse button which is a different menu (context menu)

Specs:

- Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
- Terminator 1.91